# How to wrap long text with \multicol in tables?

Tags: tables, multirow, wrap

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, mag=1000, left=3.2cm, right=3.2cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, headsep=0.7cm,headheight = 15pt, footskip=1cm,twoside}
%\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{fix-cm}

%TABLES
%
\usepackage{multirow}
%
\usepackage{hhline}
%
\usepackage{array}
%
\usepackage{booktabs}
%
\usepackage{tabu}
%
\usepackage{makecell}
\newcommand{\thickline}[1]{\Xhline{#1pt}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]

\caption{sd}

\begin{center}
\small
\begin{tabu}{|[2pt] >{\centering}p{3cm}  >{\centering}p{2.4cm} |[2pt] >{\centering} p{1.5cm} | >{\centering} p{3.2cm} | >{\centering} p{3.2cm}|[2pt]}
\tabucline[2pt]{-}    
& {Items} &  Responses & Percentage based on total responses ($\rm N'=169$) & Percentage based on who responded to the question ($\rm N=52$)  \\\tabucline[2pt]{-}

\multirow{7}{*}{\parbox{2.5cm}{What is you general field of expertise regarding software development? }}&  Requirements elicitation / modelling /analysis & 25 & 14.8\,\% & 48.1\,\% \\
& Project management & 25 & 14.8\,\% & 48.1\,\%\\
& Architecture & 20 & 11.8 & 38.5\,\%\\
& Design & 29 & 17.2\,\% & 55.8\,\%\\
& Coding & 35 & 20.7\,\% & 67.3\,\%\\
& Testing & 23 & 13.6\,\% & 44.2.1\,\%\\
& Documentation & 12 & 7.1\,\% & 23.1\,\%\\
\tabucline[2pt]{-}
\end{tabu}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

It gives this:[image]

As you can see command:

```
\multirow{7}{*}{\parbox{2.5cm}{What is you general field of expertise regarding software development? }}
```

does not work properly. How I can solve this problem?

Thank You in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this be what you seek?

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, mag=1000, left=3.2cm, right=3.2cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, headsep=0.7cm,headheight = 15pt, footskip=1cm,twoside}
%\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{fix-cm}

%TABLES
%
\usepackage{multirow}
%
\usepackage{hhline}
%
\usepackage{array}
%
\usepackage{booktabs}
%
\usepackage{tabu}
%
\usepackage{makecell}
\newcommand{\thickline}[1]{\Xhline{#1pt}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]

\caption{sd}

\begin{center}
\small
\begin{tabu}{|[2pt] >{\centering}p{3cm}  >{\centering}p{2.4cm} |[2pt] >{\centering} p{1.5cm} | >{\centering} p{3.2cm}| >{\centering}p{3.2cm}|[2pt]}
\tabucline[2pt]{-}  
& {Items} &  Responses & Percentage based on total responses ($\rm N'=169$) & Percentage based on who responded to the question ($\rm N=52$)  \\ \tabucline[2pt]{-}
\multirow{7}{*}{\parbox{2.5cm}{What is you general field of expertise regarding software development?}} & \multirow{7}{*}{\parbox{2cm}{Requirements elicitation / modelling /analysis}} & \multirow{7}{*}{25} &\multirow{7}{*}{14.8\,\%} &\multirow{7}{*}{48.1\,\%} \\
&&&&\\
&&&&\\
&&&&\\
&&&&\\
&&&&\\
&&&&\\
& Project management & 25 & 14.8\,\% & 48.1\,\%\\
& Architecture & 20 & 11.8\,\% & 38.5\,\%\\
& Design & 29 & 17.2\,\% & 55.8\,\%\\
& Coding & 35 & 20.7\,\% & 67.3\,\%\\
& Testing & 23 & 13.6\,\% & 442.1\,\%\\
& Documentation & 12 & 7.1\,\% & 23.1\,\%\\
\tabucline[2pt]{-}
\end{tabu}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```